# Can't call WPDB inside RSS template

Tags: wpdb, rss

I'm trying to create a custom RSS feed that will list and display information from a custom table I've created, that I use elsewhere in my WP site. The table and everythign work fine.

However, even when I try to use a simple RSS template (which is set up and browseable):

```
<?php /* Template Name: Custom RSS Template - beforeAfters  */
header('Content-Type: '.feed_content_type('rss-http').'; charset='.get_option('blog_charset'), true);
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>';
?>
<rss version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
>
<channel>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$beforeAfter = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT * FROM wp_before_after WHERE `gallery_display` = 1');
foreach($beforeAfter as $imageSet) { ?>
<item>
<title><?php echo get_the_title($imageSet->ID); ?></title>
</item>
<?php } ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I get this error:

> This page contains the following errors: error on line 11 at column
>   51: Entity 'trade' not defined Below is a rendering of the page up to
>   the first error.

A blank page is displayed (because nothing is rendered). However, if I remove the line where `$beforeAfter` is set, the error disappears and I begin to see the output of the RSS feed in a browser (although it displays errors about the `foreach` line being invalid.. which is fine.

But my question is, why is the `$wpdb` call, causing the error message, and how do I get the variable to pull the database row working so I Can use the variables within the RSS template?

** DUMP of $beforeAfter**

```
<pre class="xdebug-var-dump" dir="ltr">
<small>
C:\wamp64\www\bellavou\wp-content\themes\bellavou\rss-beforeAfters.php:17:
</small>
<b>object</b>
(
<i>stdClass</i>
)[
<i>4196</i>
]
<i>public</i>
'id'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<small>string</small>
<font color="#cc0000">'1'</font>
<i>(length=1)</i>
<i>public</i>
'created'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<font color="#3465a4">null</font>
<i>public</i>
'before_date'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<font color="#3465a4">null</font>
<i>public</i>
'after_date'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<font color="#3465a4">null</font>
<i>public</i>
'patientID'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<small>string</small>
<font color="#cc0000">'2137'</font>
<i>(length=4)</i>
<i>public</i>
'procedureID'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<small>string</small>
<font color="#cc0000">'238'</font>
<i>(length=3)</i>
<i>public</i>
'patient_display'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<small>string</small>
<font color="#cc0000">'1'</font>
<i>(length=1)</i>
<i>public</i>
'procedure_display'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<small>string</small>
<font color="#cc0000">'1'</font>
<i>(length=1)</i>
<i>public</i>
'gallery_display'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<small>string</small>
<font color="#cc0000">'1'</font>
<i>(length=1)</i>
<i>public</i>
'before_img'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<small>string</small>
<font color="#cc0000">'face-lift_1_b.jpg'</font>
<i>(length=17)</i>
<i>public</i>
'after_img'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<small>string</small>
<font color="#cc0000">'face-lift_1_a.jpg'</font>
<i>(length=17)</i>
<i>public</i>
'period_taken'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<small>string</small>
<font color="#cc0000">'1week'</font>
<i>(length=5)</i>
<i>public</i>
'notes'
<font color="#888a85">=></font>
<small>string</small>
<font color="#cc0000">''</font>
<i>(length=0)</i>
</pre>
```

Comment: Just after the $wpdb call can you dump $beforeAfter for us?

Comment: There's a lot there, I think pasting it as text might be a bit too much, a screenshot might be more helpful to read it...

Comment: Text is better, how much is "a lot"? Or see if there is a record within it with "trade" in.

Comment: No value of 'trade' was found, apart from the error message. So WPDB is getting connected then.

Comment: It was $beforeAfter I was after rather than the error in your browser.  I'm assuming that the call to $wpdb is OK.  You know it returns an object and you are looping as though it's an array?  Try removing your foreach loop a moment and see if you still get an error.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. Dumping `$beforeAfter` does return the row of the table I specified. But the error is still in the display, with the plain text dump underneath it. And removing the foreach, does remove the error, and shows the RSS feed structure, with the vardump in a `pre` block. But the foreach is quite important

Comment: Can I see $beforeAfter? Is it an object and is that object going to be happy with your foreach? Also if I see it something else might leap out.  I understand that the foreach is important, but I think it's the foreach or its contents that are at fault.  I can't tell without seeing $beforeAfter.

Comment: Yeah sure, I've replaced the image with the var_dump of $beforeAfter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42986/discussion-between-andy-macaulay-brook-and-lee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing we've discovered the problem isn't directly with calling $wpdb->get_row but a mismatch between the data it returns and the processing in the foreach loop.

For a single row of data, replacing...

```
foreach($beforeAfter as $imageSet) { ?>
    <item>
        <title><?php echo get_the_title($imageSet->ID); ?></title>
    </item>
<?php }
```

... with ...

```
<item>
    <title><?php echo get_the_title($imageSet->ID); ?></title>
</item>
```

... stops the feed erroring.

Or for multiple rows you could adjust your query.